# How to achieve "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

*sorry, I wanna to know that apple's underlying code implementation*

Comment: Underlying implementation

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear. Please [edit] your question and clearly explain what your issue or your question is.

Answer (score 0):

In storyboards you can set identifier of each of the cells you put inside the table view by setting any text to `Identifier` field:

[image]

The text in your code must be exactly the same, case sensitive to use it.

There are also ways of doing this programmatically to register a cell on table view before using it (setting it in `viewDidLoad` should be enough).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[MyTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyTableViewCellIdentifier"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyTableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyTableViewCellIdentifier"];
    return myCell;
}
```